# Web Snapshots with HTTPS: cutycapt and webkit2png

Tags: http, https, cutycapt

I was wondering if anybody has ever managed to get a screen scraping / Web Snapshot script to work well with https sites? I have a script which runs and some of the SSL sites work okay.

The problem is (I believe) that some servers are looking for an HTTP header in the client request once it has been assigned and will just throw up an access 
denied if the client doesn't have the header.

And ideas or advice appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL that results in that screenshot?

Comment: https://encompass.willis.com

Comment: Yeah, I can't get a screenshot of that either. I tried changing the UA and adding some headers Chrome would normally send along with the request to no avail. I'm not sure whether they're screening requests or there's a quirk in their server responses that trip up CutyCapt.